# Can weak attacks disable shields?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does the attack have to be a critical, strong, or knockback attacks to disable a shield?

Comment: "Disable", or 'break'?

Comment: @Joachim Disable

Answer (score 2):

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shield#Defense) (emphasis mine):

> Shields are used for blocking incoming attacks. [...] **attacks coming from in front of the player are blocked, dealing no damage. When the shield blocks an attack of 3♥♥ or stronger, it takes durability damage equal to the strength of the attack rounded up.**
>
> **Most blocked projectiles that carry status effects (such as shulker bullets‌, flaming arrows, or tipped arrows) do not affect the blocker.** Tridents & arrows can be deflected into other targets. Knockback from melee attacks and projectiles is prevented, while knockback from explosions, hoglin and ravager attacks is significantly reduced.

However, there are some things that can affect the user through the shield:

> They cannot block:
>
> - Arrows from a crossbow enchanted with Piercing
>
>   - This does not reduce the shield's durability.
> - Status effects from tipped arrows
>
>   - Direct projectile damage is blocked, but the effect still carries through.
> - Status effects from splash/lingering potions, evokers' fangs, or breath from the ender dragon
> - Beam attacks from guardians or elder guardians
> - TNT that the blocking player lit themselves‌
> - TNT that a redstone mechanism lit‌
> - Teleport and fall damage

**But most importantly:**

> - Strikes from any axe-wielding mob (e.g., vindicators, piglin brutes, zombies) or from axe-wielding players that are sprinting
>
>   - Such axe strikes disable the shield for 5 seconds‌.
>   - Axe strikes from a player that isn't sprinting still have a 25% chance to disable the shield.

So, to answer your question: the *type* of attack has no effect on the shield, other than durability. The difference is in what *causes* the attack - e.g the "Piercing" enchantment on a crossbow, or using an Axe instead of a Sword.